History of the Differential Calculus - Taylor theorem
Who used, for the first time, integration by parts to prove Taylor expansion theorem?
This question was categorized as off-topic. Scandal. Please reconsider your decision.

History of Science and Mathematics might be a better place for your question.

Brook Taylor (1685 - 1731) invented and utilized integration by parts to prove the Taylor expansion theorem (https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Taylor/). I should note that integration by parts isn't necessary to prove Taylor's Theorem. At the time, Taylor's approached differed in that he used this new method.

Pringsheim showed that it is possible to derive Taylor’s theorem from
Bernoulli’s formula by some changes of variable. However, there seems
to be no indication that Taylor did this, nor that Bernoulli
appreciated the final form or generality of the Taylor theorem.
Taylor’s Proposition XI, Theorem IV, on the other hand, is directly
equivalent to Bernoulli’s integration formula. However, Taylor’s
derivation differs from Bernoulli’s in such a way as to entitle him to
priority for the process of integration by parts.
https://www.encyclopedia.com...

